# Why does my keyboard not work in QEMU's EFI shell?

Tags: keyboard, efi, qemu

I'm trying to install Chromium OS from ArnoldtheBat's builds. However, because of the custom boot process of Chrome OS, I have to modify the EFI manually. So, I get to the EFI shell, but I can not type anything! I use a [custom QEMU](https://github.com/knazarov/homebrew-qemu-virgl) for Macbook M1. Here is my command:

```
sudo qemu-system-aarch64 \
-M virt,accel=hvf,highmem=off -m 7G \
-cpu cortex-a57 \
-hda system.bin \
-smp 4 \
-device virtio-gpu-gl-pci,xres=2880,yres=1650 \
-display cocoa,gl=es \
-bios edk2-aarch64-code.fd \
-device virtio-keyboard-pci \
-nic none \
-device qemu-xhci,id=usb-controller-1 \
```

Comment: Chromium OS from ArnoldtheBat's builds has no vm support

Comment: @Madhubala Is there a better option for aarch64 hosts? The best available are Cloudready's images, but they're Intel only. I was scared of that, but I heard other people say that it should work fine (though they left out the steps to use it -- maybe they were only referring to the x86_64 images?).

Comment: Fyde { chromeos fork for china} support arm65 - https://fydeos.com/download/device/pinebook-pro ; you can't run tis on qemu but you can dualboot; there are other things you should know - read this https://fydeos.com/help/faq#what-is-fydeos-what-is-the-significance-of-this-system

Comment: @Madhubala I've heard of it, but I hadn't considered it. Why can't it work in QEMU (for the record, I tried booting it with EFI, and it failed)?

Comment: Trying to boot it manually (with the Arch kernel and the Arch initrd image) lead me to realize that the images are 32-bit, not 64-bit like a thought. This usually doesn't matter because most kernels are compiled for 32-bit (including this one), but for whatever reason, I can't run the commands in the manually mounted root fs (located in partition 3). So, now I have to find a compiled Chromium OS for arm64 to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tianocore has no driver for the virtio keyboard, use usb instead.

Comment: I also tried `-usbdevice keyboard` but it also didn't work -- maybe because Macbooks don't have USB keyboards?